Make a word optional between a negative lookbehind and a target word
This regex (?<!not)\s(hello\W*world) will not match when hello world is preceded by not word.
How do I make it not match too when there's a word in between: not a hello world?
I'm trying this regex (?<!not)(?:\s+.*)?\s(hello\W*world) with the (?:\s+.*)? to make the in-between word optional but doesn't seem to work.
https://regex101.com/r/HPcJ9F/1

You can't, really. You'd have to put the optional word inside the negative lookbehind, but then it's not fixed-width.

See https://regex101.com/r/OCJ9ZC/1. Match what you do not need, capture what you need.

You can use negative look behind in python with variable length assertion. You can have multiple word as optional between not and hello world. For python you need to import regex instead of re.
(?<!not.*)hello world

Demo
import regex
pattern = r"(?<!not.*)hello world"
test_str = ("not hello world pqr\n"
            "not a hello world def\n"
            "abc hello world hij\n")

print(regex.search(pattern,test_str))


Try this:
r"(?i)^(?:(?!not).)*(hello world)"

Should match a hello world that does not have any "not" instances before it. The "Hello world" will be in group 1.
Basic translation:
Match any number of characters that are not the start of phrase "not". After that, match the string "hello world". If not is matched the loop ends so hello world can never be matched.
Shouldn't catastrophically backtrack.
Regex 101
